Angular 17 guard always redirecting to login with firebase auth
I'm trying to write a simple guard for my application. My auth system is based on firebase, with the possibility to login with Google.
This is my guard code:
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService)
  console.log("Guard state: ", authService.user)

  if(!authService.isLoggedIn()){
    inject(Router).navigate(['login'])
  }

  return authService.isLoggedIn()
}


The authService.isLoggedIn() method just returns the value of auth.currentUser.
Now, if I call this function, let's say, in my app-component with a (click) event, everything works fine, but inside the guard I always get a false.
I suspect the problem is with the service injection, maybe a new instance of the AuthService is created every time, losing all my reference to the actual authentication situation.
Any idea?

Does your logging show the auth user or undefined?  Is your AuthService using {providedIn: 'root'}?

I track the auth state with onAuthStateChanged() so I know that a user is logged in.

I solved it by creating a new Promise inside of my authService. The Promise is resolved or rejected inside the onAuthStateChanged() so I can just make async the canActivate method and wait for the auth state to be updated.

You can directly use
import { AuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
const unauthRedirect = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['/signin']);

export const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'account',
    component: AccountComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { authGuardPipe: unauthRedirect }
},
... 
]

